# Application Insights Client library retry logic, when network is not available

Tags: javascript, azure-application-insights

I am using Application Insights JavaScript library in my application to log telemetry data. I need to know if the AI library provides a retry method? In case, when the network (internet) is back up after a downtime (not connected to internet), would it retry to send data or would I loose telemetry data, for the time when the network was down? I am using vortex along with Application Insights to send telemetry data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a retry mechanism in the Application Insights SDK as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-application-insights-javascript-sdk-reliability-and-performance-improvements/):

> Retry and error handling features are helping to improve transmission reliability. In the case of network issues, the SDK will retry sending the telemetry data with an exponential backoff.